# jquery toggle html text

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, toggle

I am trying to show a hidden div that is triggered by an a tag click:

Button Code Looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;"  class="viewMoreProducts">View Related Products</a>
```

Here is my jquery for when i click the button:

```
// Show Hidden Product Boxes on Expand - More Products and More Link
$(".viewMoreProducts").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle(300, function (){
        if ($(this).parent().find(".moreProductsBox").is(":visible")){ 
            $(this).find(":input").addClass("visibleCounter");

        }
        if ($(this).parent().find(".moreProductsBox").is(":hidden")){ 
            $(this).find(":input").removeClass("visibleCounter");
        }
    });
});
```

I can get the toggle of the hidden div working just fine but i also want to change the text on the a link to change when the div is showing, to then show it has "Hide Related Products" and show a different icon to collapse. Then if i collapse it, it goes back to read View Related Products and has the plus icon.

Any way to just add it to the jquery that i have already?

This sounds pretty straight forward but giving me the run around.

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (assuming the multiple parent()s can't be simplified further):

```
$(".viewMoreProducts").click( function(){
  var that = this; // reference to the <a>
  $(this).parent().parent().parent()
      .find(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle(300, function (){
        var isvisible = $(this).parent().find(".moreProductsBox").is(":visible");
        $(this).find(":input").toggleClass('visibleCounter', isvisible); 
        $(that).html( (isvisible ? 'Hide It' : 'Show It') );
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" class="viewMoreProducts">View Related Products</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".viewMoreProducts").click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".moreProductsBox:first").slideToggle(300, function () {
        var $input = $(this).find(":input");
        if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
            $input.addClass("visibleCounter");
            $button.text('Hide Related Products');
        } else {
            $input.removeClass("visibleCounter");
            $button.text('View Related Products');
        }
    });
    return false; // allows you to remove that onclick attribute
});
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working. It opens the hidden div and the wont let me close it, nor does the text change when you click it.

Comment: @estern Maybe the if statement equation is not resolving to `true`, try `$(this).is(":visible")` and putting an alert in the first code block of the if statement (the bit which executes when true) and let me know if that is executing when it should.

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow: i added an alert to both the if and the else and nothing pops up for either. Sounds like the if declaration is not calling the right thing.

Comment: @estern Ah, an unnecessary line would have been causing a syntax error. It was the line underneath `var $input = $(this).find(":input");` try it without that.

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow: Thank you for you help, i decided to go another route with the simpler code from @Ken Redler. Cheers

Comment: @Marcus Whybrow: You did teach me how to not do the onclick="return false"... Thank you for this. This will be very helpful.

Comment: @estern No problem, just joking about.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this a bit old fashioned:

```
var x = this.innerHTML;
this.innerHTML = x.replace("show","z").replace("hide","show").replace("z","hide");
```